# Can pyside-uic Compile a ui file with QButtonGroups

Tags: python, compilation, pyqt, pyside

Ive got a .ui file made in designer and as soon as i group some radio buttons together, pyside-uic fails to compile the file and return with an unexpected error.

Is there a way around this or am i missing something when adding these groups.  Im picking the buttons i need, right clicking and creating a button group from there.

Here is the most basic version of the ui, and this even crashes for me.

http://pastebin.com/0NYHPBUD

Comment: Can you provide the UI file for people to look at?

Comment: Im not sure how i upload files here, but it happens with a form as simple as 4 radio buttons, split between 2 buttongroups

Comment: You can either copy/paste the contents on the ui file into a code block or put it on something like pastebin and link to that

Comment: ah, kk, added a link tot he ui file

Answer (score 2):

after debugging pysideuic, i figured that in module uiparser.py in line 212 the generator fails, because it treats a string like an object.

By changing the source (https://github.com/PySide/Tools/pysideuic/uiparser.py) from:

```
bg_name = bg_i18n.string
```

to:

```
bg_name = bg_i18n
```

the generator will be working fine.
After further investigation it seems that the implementation of the QButtonGroup changed.
It used to be a Widget.

regards

Ben

Comment: Cheers for the info, i don't think i would've been able to find that.  Does this mean the only way to compile a ui that uses the buttonGroups is to change the source then?

Comment: Or you write an issue for the responsible developers and wait for a new release, what can take while ;-)

Comment: The link given in my first answer seems to be invalid. Here the new one https://github.com/PySide/Tools/tree/master/pysideuic 

First download "https://github.com/PySide/Tools/archive/master.zip" then change the single line in the file uiparser.py 
Once the line is changed you can easily generate the python gui by executing "python pyside-uic" or building the tool using cmake.